# Customized alerts in Javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox-addon

I am developing an addon to Firefox using addon-builder. I want to replace a normal alert box in Javascript with my addon. So, I have choosen customized alert boxes using jQuery. The jAlert details are given [here](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/).

Now, I made customized alerts (with title and colors in alert). It is wroking properly on some websites. But on some websites the default CSS is dominating my jQuery CSS, which leads to unexpected alerts (ugly alerts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution, and I usually avoid this, but it works nonetheless.

The `!important` keyword used in your CSS will force it to override any other current setting.

i.e. Normal

```
.example {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

i.e. Forced

```
.example {
    font-size: 14px !important; 
}
```

However, try and find out what CSS style is conflicting, and perhaps change the order of it applied or the naming (if that's a common parameter).

Comment: may i know, why this is not best solution?

Comment: Mostly due to the fact that it's use means that you are not using the standard flow of CSS precedence rules, which mean that each style at specific levels overrides others by default. It's inconsistent if you actual have CSS that follows the rules and then this forcing will break those rules. It also fails in IE6 (no surprise) and may fail with IE7. Read more here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/

Comment: yes, iam observing some changes in original website with my css override. iam going for alternates,  can u explain about "change the order of it applied or the naming" in your previous answer

Comment: Order applied read a good article here http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: As for the naming, it only make sense that an object (i.e. div) with a class (i.e. myclass) can get CSS styles inherited, for it's object name, type or id or it's class. If you have conflicting styles, it could be due to the fact that your specified class has another style already applied to it, hence changing the name you use might overcome this.